# What is the estimated timeline for Release Readiness of the Office Store?

Tags: office-addins, office-store

our Microsoft Office Add-In submission to the Office Store made it through the Validation process and as seen in the following screenshot, we have reached **Release readiness** and are very excited about it.
[image: Submission Status]

However we are a bit confused about the estimated time (delay) it will take until the app becomes publicly available. Is there a way for us to plan the launch and do we have to wait until the app is published to update links to it on our website or can we access it beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app submission workflow service within the Seller Dashboard service is experiencing delays and your submission may be impacted.  The Seller Dashboard status of your submission may not accurately reflect the actual status.  Our engineers are fully engaged to resolve this issue. We will contact you if you are required to take any action as a result of this.

If this is the first time your submission has been approved, no link will be available at present. If this is an update to an existing submission, the link will not have changed.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response addressing both questions, we're looking forward see our app in the store hopefully soon

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic